Film about inmate who receives alien DNA
In the mid-2000s, my cousin and I rented and watched a B/C-list sci-fi movie that was hugely disappointing, but I cannot remember its title.
Synopsis:
An inmate is given alien DNA that supposedly gives him enhanced physical abilities. The film is spliced with footage of him interviewing about himself from within prison, with him discussing his outlook on life and what-not.
He is released from prison to track down an extraterrestrial enemy that I believe is personified as a green goo that infests people. The film's climax takes place at night at an ally policeman's house, where the inmate appears to defeat the entity, then falls into the pool dead.
The resolution has the policeman and his wife getting frisky. He lays down on bed while his wife mounts him. As he smiles with his eyes closed, his wife is revealed to be infested and we end with a cut to black as she attacks with her mouth open.
The cover of the film featured an alien claw holding a human assault rifle... which, yes, is incredibly misleading.

Choker (AKA Disturbance) from 2005, though if you hated it I'm not sure why you want to subject yourself to this again. ;)

Hud Masters (Paul Sloan) is released from prison to hunt down a viral like alien race. He is taken to an agency, where he is partnered with Logan (Colleen Porch) to undergo such a mission. Together they fight their way though a horde of alien infestation in the city, until they reach the leader (Hayley Dumond).

Here's that misleading poster:


Oh yeah, that's the special movie! Tell me, do you like it?

Vaguely recall it was a bit better than I expected, but I didn't expect much, which might be the key. ;)
